# Is it possible to overwrite a certain part of a txt file in php?

Tags: php, html, file, text, overwrite

Let's say we have a .txt file with the text "1234567890",
is it possible to change the 1 to a 9 so it says "9234567890" without touching the remaining numbers?

To clarify, it should **only** change a part of the text file and not rewrite the entire thing. I'm only allowed to use php and html.

Comment: Can you explain why you think rewriting "only part" is different from "rewriting the entire thing"? Because the bytes on disk are going to be identical.

Comment: Not sure how to explain my program but I have 3 'option'-buttons with "X" or "-" as options. I want to be able to select one "X" and two "-" and send it into a document (for example, It'll look like this "X--"). The buttons will reset and I want to be able to pick another "X" in another position, e.g. this line "-X-" and have the document output to be "XX-" rather than "X---X-".

As I said, not sure how to explain it easily but hopefully you get the picture. What kainaw said in his post is exactly what I'm looking for though, so thanks for that one!

Comment: it's better not to add that as information hidden in a comment, edit your post with that clarification so people don't need to read through a comment thread to get all the information for question. Then you can post a comment saying "I updated my post with more information" and everyone is better off. In this case, it doesn't seem like it'd matter, you can easily regenerate the entire document (since it's small) instead of using a "slice and insert" approach. Both work, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a one-liner, but I'm breaking it up so it makes more sense. Further, this would be faster using exec with sed or awk, but this is just PHP here.

```
$string = file_get_contents("yourfile");
$string = str_replace('1','9',$string);
file_put_contents("youfile", $string);
```